# When button is clicked, rather than redirecting, it just removes table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I have a table dynamically generated form a sql server that has nested buttons in a cell. When clicked the buttons are supposed to redirect to another page. But, currently when the buttons are clicked, the page refreshed and shows the page without the generated table. 
  I've put a breakpoint in the method that the buttons call on onclick, and when I click the button the breakpoint is never reached.

**Markup:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" runat="server">  
    <tr>  
        <td align="center">  
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="dbPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>  
        </td>  
    </tr>  
</table>
```

**Method called on page**

```
private void Create_Table()
{

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        //Connect to databse and grab table
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CCPOF_ID, Job_Number, Project_Name, CompletedBy, DateCreated FROM My_Table", conn);
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dataTable = new DataTable();
        table = new Table();
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }

    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#bd0000");
    row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    TableHeaderCell headerCell;

    string[] headerName = {"ID", "Job #", "Project", "Completed By", "Date Created", "  "};
    //Add Headers
    for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Columns.Count + 1; j++)
    {
        headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();
        headerCell.Text = headerName[j];
        row.Cells.Add(headerCell);
    }
    table.Rows.Add(row);

    //Add Columns
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        row = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Columns.Count+1; j++)
        {
            if (j < dataTable.Columns.Count)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Text = dataTable.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }
            else
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();

            Button btnEdit = new Button();
            btnEdit.OnClientC‌​lick = "btnEdit_Click";
            btnEdit.ID = "Edit" + dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            btnEdit.Attributes.Add("name", "Edit" + dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString());
            btnEdit.CssClass = "astext";
            btnEdit.Text = "Edit ";
            cell.Controls.Add(btnEdit);

            Button btnDetail = new Button();
            btnDetail.OnClientC‌​lick = "btnDetail_Click";
            btnDetail.ID = "Detail" + dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            btnDetail.Attributes.Add("name", "Detail" + dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString());
            btnDetail.CssClass = "astext";
            btnDetail.Text = "Details";
            cell.Controls.Add(btnDetail); 

                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }
        }
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    table.CssClass = "table table-bordered";

    //Add Table to Markup
    dbPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(table);
}
```

**Other methods...**
//Methods need to be update but, doesn't matter because they are never called

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)sender).ID;
    Server.Transfer("CcpofDetails.aspx?ID=" + id);// To be changes to different page later
}

protected void btnDetail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)sender).ID;
    Server.Transfer("CcpofDetails.aspx?ID=" + id); 
}
```

Comment: change `btnDetail.OnClientClick = "btnDetail_Click";` to `btnDetail.Click += new EventHandler(btnDetail_Click);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a few things to fix this...

- Added

  ```
   <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>
  ```
- Made the Postback recreate the table everytime
- Used Command to add the Onclick feature

  ```
   btnEdit.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.btnEdit_Click);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect event mapping in your dynamic buttons.

1. [OnClientClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can be used when you want to invoke client-side
   script.
2. [Click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click(v=vs.110).aspx) has to be used when you want to bind a
   server-side event.

So, remove the below line of code

```
btnEdit.OnClientClick = "btnEdit_Click";
```

and add this line

```
btnEdit.Click += new EventHandler(btnEdit_Click);
```

Comment: still refreshes page and removes table

Comment: Are you able to hit breakpoint? Did you add Click event for both buttons? What is inside your button_click?

Comment: Breakpoint is never reached, code has been update in original post to show other methods

Comment: Did you remove `OnClientClick` for two buttons and add `Click` event? Also, you may need to use `Response.Redirect`!

Comment: Yes i did remove them.

Comment: You are not supposed to update the same question with the answers provided; it will lose context; One question has to deal with one problem